# Issues colouring text HTML/CSS with hovered text

Tags: html, css, text, colors, hover

I've been learning html/css over the last couple days and have made a few beginner pages.
I've tried to put a basic hover overlay over the large picture. The hover overlay has some basic text and a low opacity grey fill over the image. My problem is that i think the text is appearing behind the overlay. So the text seems to slightly change colour but going from black to white isn't clear etc.
I hope this is a bit more specific and accommodates to guidelines.
Thanks to whoever helps me!!

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>SHAYMAC</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header id="main-header">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>SHAYMAC</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  <nav id="nav-bar">
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.google.com/">home</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">about</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">service</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="pic">
      <div class="text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</p></div>
  </div>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

css code

```
body{
  background-color:#333;
  color:#fff;
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin:0;
}
.container{
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.pic{
  background-image: url(../images/desk.jpg);
  background-position: center ;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-bottom:30px;
  text-align: center ;
}
.pic:hover{
  opacity:0.3;
  filter: alpha(opacity=30);
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.text{
  padding-top:135px;
  color:#000;
  opacity:0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.pic:hover .text{
     color:#fff;
     opacity:0.6;
     text-align: center;
     font-size:20px;
     font-weight:700;
     font-family:"Arial", Times, serif;
     padding-top:135px;
     transition: .5s ease;
     position:relative;
}
#main-header{
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  padding:10;

}
#nav-bar{
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;

}

#nav-bar ul{
  padding:10;
  list-style: none;

}

#nav-bar li{
  display: inline;

}

#nav-bar a{
  color:#fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:18px;
  padding-right:15px;

}

#nav-bar a: hover{
  color: #coral;
}
#showcase{
  background-image: url(../images/showcase.jpg);
  background-position: center right;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-bottom:30px;
  text-align: center ;
}
#showcase h1{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Show CODE, Not PICTURES of CODE!!! Instead click edit, then `[<>]` stacksnippet and give us a working example

Comment: Please share the code you have so far in order for us to be able to help. Otherwise, you will probably not get help because your question is too broad

Comment: Please share code as text and not as print-screens. No one has time to rewrite your code and guess the missing parts in order to help you

Answer (score 0):

I think there could be one of 2 problems one could be your opacity of the text because it is set to 0.6 instead of 1 that's why it looks like there is a gray overlay another thing is as you mentioned in your question it could be behind to fix this one you need to add z-index:10; to your text in your css

hope 1 of these 2 solutions may help you with your journey :)